# How to Get the Array of data from json array using WEB API in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf-web-api

I have create web services using Web Api in mvc3,in this i want get the data from json. Json Result like this

```
   {"order": {
  "locationid": "1",
   "deviceidentifier": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "ordercontactname": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "ordercontactphone": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "ordercontactemail": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "shipaddress1": "17 Brookfield",
   "shipaddress2": "Suite 17",
   "shipcity": "Irvine",
   "shipstate": "CA",
   "shipzipcode": "92604",
   "shipphonenumber": "9493742114",
   "shipemail": "Info@mail.com",
   "shipmethod": "pickup",
   "billingfirstname":"Tester",
   "billinglastname":"test",
   "billingmiddleinitial":"S",
   "billingaddress":"field",
   "billingcity":"Sample",
   "billingstate":"SM",
   "billingzipcode":"523201",
   "billingphonenumber": "1234567891",
   "billingemail": "",
   "paytype":"creditcard",
  "amount"="10.50",
  "acctno"="123456789987",
  "exproute"="0114",
  "coupon"="X2323",
  "notes"="",
   "items": [
   {"itemid":"1","quantity":"1","price":"2.5","notes":"make it spicy"},
   {"itemid":"4","quantity":"2","price":"4.5","notes":""},
   {"itemid":"3","quantity":"1","price":"1.5","notes":""}
    ]
  }}
```

for this i have create Poco class and i get Order data using poco class, but i can't get the items array data how can i get items data

```
Here is my code

     public List<Message> PlaceOrder(PlaceOrder  order)
       {
          //  List<PlaceOrder> entities =         (List<PlaceOrder>)JavaScriptConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(List<PlaceOrder>));
        int PayOrderID = 0;
        List<Message> Result;
        Result = new List<Message>();
        try
        {
            Order objOrder = new Order();
            PayHist objPayhis = new PayHist();
            objOrder.LocationId = order.LocationId;
            objOrder.DeviceIdentifier = order.DeviceIdentifier;
            objOrder.OrderContactName = order.OrderContactName;
            objOrder.OrderContactPhone = order.OrderContactPhone;
            objOrder.OrderContactEmail = order.OrderContactEmail;
            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            objOrder.ShipMethod = order.ShipMethod;
            objOrder.ShippingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(order.PickupDate);
            objOrder.OrderGuid = guid;
            entities.AddObject("Orders", objOrder);
            entities.SaveChanges();
            int orderId = objOrder.OrderId;
            PayOrderID = orderId;
            objPayhis.OrderId = orderId;
            objPayhis.PayType = order.ShipMethod;
            objPayhis.Amount = float.Parse(order.Amount);
            entities.AddObject("PayHists", objPayhis);
            entities.SaveChanges();
            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
           // Order foo = ser.Deserialize<Order>(json);

            Message objMessage = new Message();
            objMessage.Messagevalue = "Sucess";
            Result.Add(objMessage);
            return Result;


        }
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Try this (you need to fix your Json by replacing the "=" signs by ":" signs" before):

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "")]
public HttpResponseMessage Add(JsonValue json) {
    JsonValue order = json["order"];
    JsonArray items = (JsonArray) order["items"];
    JsonValue item1 = items[0];
    var notes1 = item1["notes"];
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response i have tested this using fiddler in that header i have added content-type and accept headers to "application/json" it showing 500 internal error.

Comment: My question is how can i get the nested array data to store in my db with same order id.

Comment: when i run the fiddler it shows 500 Internal error.But when pass the json like    " {"LocationId":5,"DeviceIdentifier":"N","OrderContactName":"Victor","OrderContactPhone":"1234569874","OrderContactEmail":"info@ses","ShipMethod":"PickUp","PickupDate":"2011-09-08","Amount":"15.25","MenuItemId":"1_5_9","Quantity":"2_9_8","UnitCost":"2.25_6.65_9.95","Options":"_MakeSpicyRaost_"} " It is working ..

Comment: i have fallow this link http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20started:%20Building%20a%20simple%20web%20api  To create Webservices.

Comment: Hi i get the values of order but how can i get Item values which is having the nested array values ..

Comment: Where i can get that Json.net ,u gavew me a link in that there is content in Download.where i can get that?

Comment: Hi i have get "WebApiContrib" using nuget,But i did't under stand where i can write my code please clarify me once.

Comment: actually in previous i am getting the data using poco class.when i pass the values through web service then poco-class will get all the values and assign the values to Entity class(in previous there is no nested array values) But now it hav Nested array values here i struck.